# New Ubuntu installation is too slow

Tags: windows

I downloaded Ubuntu because my windows XP Pro computer crashed. It was not recoverable because the computer was given to me without backup disks.

It is a Cisnet with a MSI motherboard Pentium 4 with 756 MiB of RAM. Ubuntu does not recognize the video hardware.

I have a handful of video cards should I try each one? 
Is the problem in the RAM or the video card?

Please help, as my computer is too slow for me to use well.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to AskUbuntu! Considering the age of your hardware, I'd recommend staying away from Ubuntu 12.10, which is optimized for newer hardware and typically needs at least 1 GiB of RAM. I'd recommend trying a lighter version of Ubuntu such as [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), or [Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Lubuntu would probably run best on your computer.

Your problem is most likely a combination of little RAM and a legacy video card.